# How to use DLT-viewer in Mac

Tags: logging, dlt-daemon

Is there a way to execute DLT on Mac devices? As i see on the website of DLT, they are saying 'it might work' but i couldn't manage it.

I installed it from the original website as dmg file, it installed to device. It is also running but here is the screen which is not usable.

[image: like this:]

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://github.com/COVESA/dlt-viewer/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instructions-for-building-dlt-viewer-with-cmake-linux-and-macos-command-line

I installed it after CMAKE build from terminal

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure..

install QT5 using brew
`brew install qt5`

pull dlt-viewer and install it
`git clone https://github.com/COVESA/dlt-viewer.git` `cmake -DQt5_DIR=$(brew --prefix qt5)/lib/cmake/Qt5 .`
`make install`

Answer (score 0):

For me, [MacDLT](https://www.fxdata.ro/macdlt) works on my m1 pro 14". Filters can be set as well. The above pic in original question is from MacDLT

Comment: hi, @thandasoru, I'm totally new to MacDLT. When I launch MacDLT, I got the same. How can I connect to my device? I see in Settings -> Connection, there is Hostname and Port configuration, but after I set that information, I see cannot see anything on MacDLT.